# Choose folder or folder directory inside shiny app

Tags: r, csv, shiny

I have a problem using shiny. I want to choose the folder where all the files I want to use in my app are saved either 1) by setting the working directory to that folderpath or 2) by uploading all csv data inside this folder to my app for further processing. for 1) I found the shinyFiles package but it is very very slow -not due to my PC- as well as giving me the error:

```
Warning: Error in dir.create: invalid 'path' argument
Stack trace (innermost first):
    59: dir.create
    58: dirCreate
    57: observerFunc
     2: runApp
     1: shinyFilesExample
```

when I selected a folder and the create folder button becomes clickable and I am putting a name of the new folder into it and clicking on the "+" beneath that panel. Anybody knows why? Despite that this method works but is very very slow. code below:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)

ui<-fluidPage(sidebarLayout(

  sidebarPanel(
    shinyDirButton("dir", "Chose directory", "Upload")
  ),

  mainPanel(
    h4("output$dir"),
    verbatimTextOutput("dir"), br()

  )

))


server <- function(input,output,session){

  # dir
  shinyDirChoose(input, 'dir', roots = getVolumes())
  dir <- reactive(input$dir)
  output$dir <- renderPrint(dir())




}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Is there another option? Maybe to upload all csv data via the `fileInput` function? Or another way? It should not work only locally but on a server so `choose.dir` might be not the right way.
Many thanks

Comment: or is it possible to load the folder with all csv. filed as a zip with the fileInput() function? then unzip it and extract all csv files?

Comment: did you try `addResourcePath()` already?

Comment: Thanks. I am new to all this programming so I tried to understand what this function does but not fully got it? Can the user of the app browse and add a resource path or is it a fixed one that I have to set up before? Because the directory will change for every user using the app as he/she has saved the folder at another place.

Answer (score 4):

so far, shinyfiles is the only way to input folders, as far as I know. It cannot work on a server, because browsers are not allowed to select folders (for security reasons).

The zipping way might be the only way to go if you want it to be working on a server (but I have no clue if it can actually be done)

Answer (score 1):

The funktion **getwd()** gets your current working directory.

```
server <- function(input,output,session){

  # dir
  shinyDirChoose(input, 'dir', roots = c(name=getwd()))
  dir <- reactive(input$dir)
  output$dir <- renderPrint(dir())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If there are not too many files in your directory, you can just use `fileInput` with `multiple=T`. You can also filter them by extension.

```
 ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        # ?fileInput
        fileInput("file1", "Choose HTML File(s)", multiple=T, accept = ".html")
      ),
      mainPanel(
        verbatimTextOutput("out.print")
      )
    )
  )

  
  server <- function(input, output) {
    
    output$out.print <- renderPrint({
      file <- input$file1
      ext <- tools::file_ext(file$datapath)
      
      req(file)
      validate(need(ext == "html", "Please upload  html  file(s)"))
      
      file 
    })
 
  }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

However, if  you have too many files, it seems like [library(shinyFiles)](https://github.com/thomasp85/shinyFiles) remains to be your option

Comment: thanks for adding this alternative!