# Get the path for a folder chosen by user in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I would like the user to be able to choose a folder (Ill retrieve the path for this later).

At the moment this works for selection of a file but not a folder. I cant explain why. And the directory does have files in it (tested on windows and mac).
Any ideas?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)


ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyFilesButton("Btn_GetFile", "Choose a file" ,
                   title = "Please select a file:", multiple = FALSE,
                   buttonType = "default", class = NULL),
  shinyDirButton('folder', 'Folder select', 'Please select a folder', FALSE),

  textOutput("txt_file")     
)


server <- function(input,output,session){

  volumes = getVolumes()
  observe({  
    shinyFileChoose(input, "Btn_GetFile", roots=volumes, session = session)

    if(!is.null(input$Btn_GetFile)){
      # browser()
      file_selected<-parseFilePaths(volumes, input$Btn_GetFile)
      output$txt_file <- renderText(as.character(file_selected$datapath))
    }
  })

  observe({  
    if(!is.null(input$Btn_Folder)){
      # browser()
      shinyDirChoose(input, 'folder', roots=volumes)
      dir <- reactive(input$folder)
      output$dir <- renderText(as.character(dir()))
    }
  })


}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Choose folder or folder directory inside shiny app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43263867/choose-folder-or-folder-directory-inside-shiny-app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you wrote `Btn_Folder` instead of `folder` here:

```
  observe({  
    if(!is.null(input$Btn_Folder)){
      shinyDirChoose(input, 'folder', roots=volumes)
      dir <- reactive(input$folder)
      output$dir <- renderText(as.character(dir()))
    }
  })
```

Replace with:

```
  observe({  
    if(!is.null(input$folder)){
      shinyDirChoose(input, 'folder', roots=volumes)
      dir <- reactive(input$folder)
      output$dir <- renderText(as.character(dir()))
    }
  })
```

As a side note, you don't need to define this reactive conductor inside the observer, simply do:

```
  observe({  
    if(!is.null(input$folder)){
      shinyDirChoose(input, 'folder', roots=volumes)
      output$dir <- renderText(as.character(input$folder))
    }
  })
```